# Avoid copy construction by std::transform

Tags: c++, reference, std

I'm calling std::transform with a lambda that takes by reference and gives back a reference to the vector element. However, according to my program output, the copy constructor is called and the objects are NOT the same.

**Code**:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Math
{
private:
    int val_ = 5;
public:
    Math(const Math& m) {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor, our address: " << this << ", his address: " << &m << std::endl;
    }
    Math(int val) : val_(val) {
        std::cout << "Object constructed with " << val << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Math> v_math = { { 5 }, { 10 } };
    std::transform(
        begin(v_math),
        end(v_math),
        begin(v_math), 
        [](const Math& m)-> const Math&  {
            return m;
        });
}
```

**Output** (Godbolt):

```
Object constructed with 5
Object constructed with 10
Copy constructor, our address: 0x23d7ec0, his address: 0x7fff9dc499a8
Copy constructor, our address: 0x23d7ec4, his address: 0x7fff9dc499ac
```

So three things are unclear to me right now:

1. Why are the objects different? Shouldn't they be the same?
2. Why is one object's address bigger than the other? Is this because the copied-to object remains on the stack which has offset-pointers?
3. How can I avoid copy construction as well (actually I just "misuse" std::transform for a declarative way of invoking a lambda on every std::vector element)?

Comment: Three things that would improve your test program: 1) Output `this` in both constructors, not just the copy (this can help track which object gets copied. 2) Output `&m` in your lambda, again to improve tracking of objects. 3) Add output right before and after the piece of code you want to blame, so that you know you are blaming the correct line of code for the copies.

Comment: Also note that you have to do your tests in release builds. For example I know MSVC doesn't do RVO in debug builds and will call copy constructors where the release build will not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The copies have nothing to do with your usage of `std::transform`. They happen when you construct your `v_math` `std::vector`, because you're using a `std::initializer_list` constructor, which forces copies during construction.

In your `std::transform` call, `operator=(const Math&)` is called, change your code to the following to see this.

```cpp
class Math
{
private:
    int val_ = 5;
public:
    Math(const Math& m) {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor, our address: " << this << ", his address: " << &m << std::endl;
    }
    Math(int val) : val_(val) {
        std::cout << "Object constructed with " << val << std::endl;
    }

    Math& operator=(const Math& other) {
        val_ = other.val_;
        std::cout << "Operator=(const Math&) called!\n";
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Math> v_math = { { 5 }, { 10 } };

    std::cout << "After constructing v_math!\n";

    std::transform(
        begin(v_math),
        end(v_math),
        begin(v_math),
        [](const Math& m)-> const Math& {
            return m;
        });
    std::cout << "After std::transform call!\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that about initializer lists. What about question 2) though? I would still be interested in why the memory addresses are different size?

Comment: In your case, short address is the address on heap, and long is on stack. Vector's content is stored on heap, while {5} and {10} is temporary objects, which are created on stack.

Comment: @glades they are not, the way points are printed exactly depends on the compiler, gcc/clang seem to print only non-zero part, while msvc will print leading zeroes as well. As why they are so different/far apart, `this` pointer will be allocated on the heap by `std::vector`, while the `&m` you're making a copy of exists on the stack.